# JMenuItems not responding

Tags: java, swing, jmenu, jmenuitem, jmenubar

I have created a 3x3 memory game with colors. The program runs and displays the colors, but the `JMenuBar` is not working correctly. The button new board, play and end game are not working. Is there something wrong with my `Actionlistener`?

This is how the code should be working : https://gyazo.com/9bf3e073a9c455e56d9b4403586bfaf5?fbclid=IwAR3Zk1BZvRj49CtAz01h95zic8tk74UmyUcU2HrY3VY8XcARoD14Ke6tcoQ

**This is `StartPlayer`**

```
import gui.MemoryGameWindow;
import gui.ColoredPanel;
import gui.GamePanel;

public class StartPlayer {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
  new MemoryGameWindow();
  
}
}
```

**This is `ColoredPanel`**

```
package gui;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class ColoredPanel extends JPanel {
  private Color thisColor = null;
  
  private Color challenge = null;
  
  public ColoredPanel(Color color) {
    this.thisColor = color;
    setBackground(color);
  }
  
  public void setGameMode(Color c, MouseListener ml) {
    setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    this.challenge = c;
    System.out.println("Coloredpanel says challenge is " + this.challenge);
    addMouseListener(ml);
  }
  
  public void restoreBackground() {
    setBackground(this.thisColor);
  }
}
```

**This is `GamePanel`**

```
package gui;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class GamePanel extends JPanel {
  private Color[] colors = new Color[] { Color.GREEN, Color.YELLOW, Color.MAGENTA };
  
  private Random r = new Random();
  
  private int square = 9;
  
  private Color challenge;
  
  private int countOfPossibleHits = 0;
  
  private int countOfWinnerHits = 0;
  
  private JPanel challengeDisplay;
  
  public GamePanel(JPanel cd) {
    this.challengeDisplay = cd;
    setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 0, 2, 2));
    for (int i = 0; i < this.square; i++)
      add(new ColoredPanel(this.colors[this.r.nextInt(this.colors.length)])); 
  }
  
  public Color startGame() {
    Color[] existingColors = new Color[getComponentCount()];
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < getComponentCount(); i++)
      existingColors[i] = ((ColoredPanel)getComponent(i)).getBackground(); 
    this.challenge = existingColors[this.r.nextInt(existingColors.length)];
    this.countOfPossibleHits = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < getComponentCount(); i++) {
      if (((ColoredPanel)getComponent(i)).getBackground() == this.challenge)
        this.countOfPossibleHits++; 
    } 
    for (i = 0; i < getComponentCount(); i++)
      ((ColoredPanel)getComponent(i)).setGameMode(this.challenge, new TheMouselistener()); 
    return this.challenge;
  }
  
  class TheMouselistener extends MouseAdapter {
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
      ColoredPanel clickedObject = (ColoredPanel)e.getSource();
      clickedObject.restoreBackground();
      if (clickedObject.getBackground() != GamePanel.this.challenge) {
        clickedObject.add(new JLabel("Game Over!"));
        GamePanel.this.challengeDisplay.add(new JLabel("Game Over!"));
        System.out.println("Game Over");
        GamePanel.this.updateUI();
      } else {
        GamePanel.this.countOfWinnerHits = GamePanel.this.countOfWinnerHits + 1;
        if (GamePanel.this.countOfWinnerHits == GamePanel.this.countOfPossibleHits) {
          clickedObject.add(new JLabel("You won!"));
          GamePanel.this.challengeDisplay.add(new JLabel("You Won!"));
          GamePanel.this.updateUI();
        } 
      } 
    }
  }
}
```

**This is `MemoryGameWindow`**

```
package gui;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class MemoryGameWindow extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
  private JMenuItem newgame = null;
  
  private JMenuItem playgame = null;
  
  private JMenuItem exit = null;
  
  private GamePanel gamepanel = null;
  
  private JPanel challengeDisplay;
  
  public MemoryGameWindow() {
    setTitle("memory game");
    setLayout(new BorderLayout(5, 5));
    add(this.challengeDisplay = new JPanel() {
        
        },  "North");
    add(this.gamepanel = new GamePanel(this.challengeDisplay));
    setJMenuBar(new GameMenubar(this));
    setSize(600, 600);
    setLocationRelativeTo((Component)null);
    setVisible(true);
  }
  
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    Object s = e.getSource();
    if (s == this.newgame) {
      remove(this.gamepanel);
      remove(this.challengeDisplay);
      add(this.challengeDisplay = new JPanel() {
          
          },  "North");
      add(this.gamepanel = new GamePanel(this.challengeDisplay));
      this.playgame.setEnabled(true);
      this.gamepanel.updateUI();
    } 
    if (s == this.playgame) {
      Color challenge = this.gamepanel.startGame();
      this.challengeDisplay.setBackground(challenge);
      this.playgame.setEnabled(false);
      this.gamepanel.updateUI();
    } 
    if (s == this.exit)
      System.exit(0); 
  }
  
  class GameMenubar extends JMenuBar {
    public GameMenubar(MemoryGameWindow memoryGameWindow) {
      JMenu file;
      add(file = new JMenu("File"));
      MemoryGameWindow.this.newgame = new JMenuItem("new board");
      file.add(new JMenuItem("new board"));
      MemoryGameWindow.this.playgame = new JMenuItem("play");
      file.add(new JMenuItem("play"));
      MemoryGameWindow.this.exit = new JMenuItem("end program");
      file.add(new JMenuItem("end program"));
      MemoryGameWindow.this.newgame.addActionListener(memoryGameWindow);
      MemoryGameWindow.this.playgame.addActionListener(memoryGameWindow);
      MemoryGameWindow.this.exit.addActionListener(memoryGameWindow);
      
      
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at these two lines:

```
MemoryGameWindow.this.playgame = new JMenuItem("play");
file.add(new JMenuItem("play"));
```

First, you set the value of `playgame` to new JMenuItem.  Later in the code, you add an ActionListener to it.  That is all correct.

The problem is, the JMenuItem with the ActionListener added to it is not what you’re adding to the menu bar.  Instead, you’re adding a *brand new* JMenuItem, which has no ActionListeners added to it.

The fix is as simple as:

```
file.add(MemoryGameWindow.this.playgame);
```

Obviously, you will need to do this for your other menu items too.